# Keyboard automatically disappears from TextField in ListView.Builder

Tags: flutter, listview, textfield, bloc

I'm trying to implement a solution where a row (containing both a TextField and a Text) in ListView.Builder is automatically for every record retrieved from a webserver.
However when I want to start typing in such a TextField the keyboard appears and immediatly disappears again.
This is the code of my screen.

```
    class GameScreen extends StatelessWidget {
 static const RouteName = "/GameScreen";

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
 const horizontalMargin = 20.0;

 return Scaffold(
  appBar: getAppBar(),
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  body: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Background(),
      Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Header("Starting letter: B"),
          Expanded(
            child: ListBlocProvider(
              listWidget: GameCategoriesList(),
              itemsService: CategoriesService(),
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: horizontalMargin,
                bottom: 10,
                right: horizontalMargin,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: size.width - 40,
            height: 60,
            child: Container(
              height: 60,
              child: TextButtonWidget(
                () {
     //              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(GameScreen.RouteName);
                },
                "Stop game",
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          )
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}
}

This is the code of my ListBlocProvider:

```
class ListBlocProvider extends StatelessWidget {
final ListWidget listWidget;
final ItemsService itemsService;
final bool useColor;
final bool usePaddingTop;
final double height;
final EdgeInsets margin;

const ListBlocProvider({
  @required this.listWidget,
 @required this.itemsService,
this.useColor = true,
this.usePaddingTop = true,
this.height = 200,
this.margin,
});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
const horizontalMargin = 20.0;

return BlocProvider(
  create: (context) => ItemsBloc(itemsService: itemsService)..add(ItemsFetched()),
  child: Container(
    padding: usePaddingTop ? EdgeInsets.only(top: 10) : null,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: this.useColor ? Color.fromRGBO(10, 50, 75, 0.9) : null,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
        bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
      ),
    ),
    margin: this.margin,
    height: this.height,
    child: this.listWidget,
   ),
   );
  }
 }
```

This is the code of my List:

```
class GameCategoriesList extends ListWidget {
@override
_GameCategoriesListState createState() => _GameCategoriesListState();
}

class _GameCategoriesListState extends State<GameCategoriesList> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return BlocBuilder<ItemsBloc, ItemsState>(
  builder: (context, state) {
    if (state is ItemsFailure) {
      return Center(
        child: Text('failed to fetch categories'),
      );
    }
    if (state is ItemsSuccess) {
      if (state.items.isEmpty) {
        return Center(
          child: Text('no categories found.'),
        );
      }

      return ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          var textEditingController = TextEditingController();
          return GameCategoryItemWidget(
            key: UniqueKey(),
            categoryModel: state.items[index],
            textEditingController: textEditingController,
          );
        },
        itemCount: state.items.length,
      );
    }
    return Center(
      child: LoadingIndicator(),
    );
    },
    );
    }
    }
```

And this is the code where the both the TextField and the Text are build:

```
class GameCategoryItemWidget extends StatefulWidget {
 final CategoryModel categoryModel;
 final TextEditingController textEditingController;

 const GameCategoryItemWidget({Key key, this.categoryModel, this.textEditingController}) : 

 super(key: key);

 @override
 _GameCategoryItemWidgetState createState() => _GameCategoryItemWidgetState();
 }

 class _GameCategoryItemWidgetState extends State<GameCategoryItemWidget> {
 var formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Container(
  child: Form(
    key: this.formKey,
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 20, bottom: 10),
          child: Text(
            this.widget.categoryModel.name,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 18,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: InputField(
            InputDecoration(labelText: this.widget.categoryModel.name),
            this.widget.textEditingController,
            false,
          ),
        ),
      ],
      ),
     ),
   );
     }

   @override
  void dispose() {
   this.widget.textEditingController.dispose();
  super.dispose();
  }
   }
```

The InputField is a custom widget to hide the switch between a Material and a Cupertino version of the TextField.

I've already tried to remove the Key from the custom TextField widget. The funny part is that the input is actually working, however it can't determine for which of the TextFields in the ListView the input is determined so it adds the input to all of them. I've also tried to swap things around with making Stateless widgets Statefull, but that didn't help either.

The entire build is based upon: https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterinfinitelisttutorial.

Hoping you guys can help me.

Comment: How do you solve this issue. I am also facing same issue. Tired to edit Text in list view but keyboard just show and disappear.

Comment: I just updated Flutter, it fixed my issue.